# Convert py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject to StructType pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I"m calling a function from the scala library like below to convert avro schema to sqlschema.

```
schema = avroschema
jvm_gateway = spark_context._gateway.jvm
sqlSchema = jvm_gateway.org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters.toSqlType(schema).dataType()
```

and the type of sqlSchema returned as <class 'py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject'>. I wanted to convert to pyspark.sql.types.StructType.

Is there any way to cast this ? I'm able to print the object and expected content is available like below

```
StructType(StructField(timestamp,LongType,true), StructField(key1,IntegerType,true), StructField(key2,StringType,true))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

able to resolve this

```
sqlSchema = jvm_gateway.org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters.toSqlType(schema).dataType()
finalSchema = _parse_datatype_json_string(sqlSchema.json())
```

now the Type is "pyspark.sql.types.StructType"

Comment: My `jvm_gateway`-import does not have an `.org`-module. Do you know why this can be; which version do you use?